# How namespaces in XML and FreeMarker template work together?

Tags: dom, namespaces, rendering, freemarker, xml-namespaces

I have read a few relevant topics on here and now have a basic understanding of the namespace concept. But I still have some difficulties getting my template to work with my XML data.

When there is no namespace involved, this template and this XML works fine:

ftl:

```
${pp.doc.user1.name}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<user1>
    <name>Jack</name>
</user1>
```

However, if there is namespace defined in the XML file, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<user1 xmlns="https://example.com/xyz">
    <name>Jack</name>
</user1>
```

I got error messages:

```
Error when processing this file: data\test1.xml
FreeMarker template error: For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), or "template output" , but this has evaluated to a sequence+hash (wrapper: f.e.dom.NodeListModel):
==> pp.doc.user1.name  [in template "renderer/test.ftlh" at line 1, column 3]

----
Tip: This XML query result can't be used as string because for that it had to contain exactly 1 XML node, but it contains 0 nodes. That is, the constructing XML query has found no matches.
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
        - Failed at: ${pp.doc.user1.name}  [in template "renderer/test.ftlh" at line 1, column 1]
----
```

My current understanding is that in the ftl, I need to use `<#ftl ns_prefixes={"ns": "https://example.com/xyz"}>` or something like this, but none of the things I tried have worked. Please kindly help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `pp.doc.user1.name` you aren't using any namespace prefix, so the elements are assumed to belong to the default namespace, which is by default nothing. To set it, use `<#ftl ns_prefixes={"D": "https://example.com/xyz"}>`. `D` is a prefix reserved for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much @ddekany! I have been struggling with finding the info like this from FreeMarker's documentation. This really saved my day!

Comment: I have another question and wonder if you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75377246/freemarker-how-to-list-all-namespaces-and-all-variables-inside-each-namespace

Comment: It is in the documentation actually. See "XML namespaces" section on https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/xgui_imperative_learn.html

Comment: Yes I have read this documentation several times but had trouble grasping the idea without a concrete example like this. Anyway, now I feel much better about how the namespaces work. Thank you!