# FreeMarker: how to access value when multiple namespaces are used?

Tags: templates, namespaces, freemarker

After I got answer from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75350939/how-namespaces-in-xml-and-freemarker-template-work-together/75366360#75366360), I am facing a little more complicated problem now.

Instead of just one namespace, the XML data contains several namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<user1 xmlns="https://example.com/xyz" xmlns:ns1="https://example2.com/abc">
    <ns1:name>Jack</ns1:name>
</user1>
```

I tried this template:

```
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"D": "https://example.com/xyz", 
                    "ns1": "https://exampl2.com/abc"}>

<#assign uu= pp.doc["D:user1"]>
${(uu["ns1:name"])}
```

but got errors back:

```
The cause of aborting was:
```

Error when processing this file: data\test1.xml
FreeMarker template error: For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), or "template output" , but this has evaluated to a sequence+hash (wrapper: f.e.dom.NodeListModel):
==> (uu["ns1:name"])  [in template "renderer/test.ftlh" at line 4, column 3]

So what is the correct way to get the `name` which is inside the "ns1"? I've read the FreeMarker documentation but still couldn't figure it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the problem is that you have made typo: `exampl2` instead of `example2`. What FreeMarker (or any XML tool) will look for is an element that belongs to the `https://exampl2.com/abc` namespace URL, and has name `user1`, so because of the typo in the URL it will not find any elements.

Note that instead of `pp.doc["D:user1"]`, you can just write `pp.doc.user1`. That's the point of `D`, that it can be omitted.